# Neural network train matlab parfor problems

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, parfor

I'm trying to find where are make mistakes. Be very glad if you could help me.

Here is my problem:

In serial the train, from neural network toolbox, function behave in one way but when I put it in a parfor loop everything goes crazy.

```
>> version

ans =

8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
```

Here is a function

```
function per = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv)

hiddenLayerSize = 94;
redeT = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
redeT.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
redeT.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
redeT.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
redeT.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
redeT.divideParam.trainRatio = 80/100;
redeT.divideParam.valRatio = 10/100;
redeT.divideParam.testRatio = 10/100;
redeT.trainFcn = 'trainscg';  % Scaled conjugate gradient
redeT.performFcn = 'crossentropy';  % Cross-entropy
redeT.trainParam.showWindow=0; %default is 1)
redeT = train(redeT,tSet,Y);    
outputs = sim(redeT,CrossVal);
per = perform(redeT,Ycv,outputs);

end
```

And here is the code I'm typing:

```
Data loaded in workspace
whos
        Name            Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

        CrossVal      282x157            354192  double
        Y               2x363              5808  double
        Ycv             2x157              2512  double
        per             1x1                   8  double
        tSet          282x363            818928  double
```

Function executing in Serial

```
per = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv)

        per =

        0.90
```

Starting parallel

```
>> parpool local
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 12 workers.

ans = 

 Pool with properties: 

            Connected: true
           NumWorkers: 12
              Cluster: local
        AttachedFiles: {}
          IdleTimeout: Inf (no automatic shut down)
          SpmdEnabled: true
```

Initializing and executing the function 12 times in parallel

```
per = cell(12,1);
parfor ii = 1 : 12
per{ii} = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv);
end        

per

per = 

    [0.96]
    [0.83]
    [0.92]
    [1.08]
    [0.85]
    [0.89]
    [1.06]
    [0.83]
    [0.90]
    [0.93]
    [0.95]
    [0.81]
```

Executing again to see if random initialization brings different values

```
per = cell(12,1);
parfor ii = 1 : 12
per{ii} = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv);
end
per

per = 

    [0.96]
    [0.83]
    [0.92]
    [1.08]
    [0.85]
    [0.89]
    [1.06]
    [0.83]
    [0.90]
    [0.93]
    [0.95]
    [0.81]
```

EDIT 1:
Running the function only with for

```
per = cell(12,1);
for ii = 1 : 12
    per{ii} = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv);
end
    per

    per =

    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
    [0.90]
```

EDIT 2:
I modified my function now everything works great. Maybe the problem is when data is divided in parallel. So i divided the data before send to parallel. Tks a lot

```
function per = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv)
indt = 1:round(size(tSet,2) * 0.8) ;
indv = round(size(tSet,2) * 0.8):round(size(tSet,2) * 0.9);
indte = round(size(tSet,2) * 0.9):size(tSet,2);
hiddenLayerSize = 94;
redeT = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
redeT.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
redeT.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
redeT.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
redeT.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
redeT.divideParam.trainRatio = 80/100;
redeT.divideParam.valRatio =  10/100;
redeT.divideParam.testRatio = 10/100;

redeT.trainFcn = 'trainscg';  % Scaled conjugate gradient
redeT.performFcn = 'crossentropy';  % Cross-entropy
redeT.trainParam.showWindow=0; %default is 1)
redeT = train(redeT,tSet,Y);    
outputs = sim(redeT,CrossVal);
per = zeros(12,1);
parfor ii = 1 : 12
    redes = train(redeT,tSet,Y);
    per(ii) = perform(redes,Ycv,outputs);
end
end
```

Result:

```
>> per = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv)

per =

          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
          0.90
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the function is working correctly. In the parfor loop, you are simply running the serial version 12 times and storing all 12 results in `per`. The reason you get different results is because you divide data randomly every time. Is this the problem?

Comment: Hm but if i run a loop in the function with for its always gives me 0.9. Is this behaver normal?

Comment: Do you mean when you replace the parfor loop with just a for loop? Also, i just saw that running parfor loop twice gives same results each time, so I don't think it's random initialization. This is really strange.

Comment: i add to the question the results running only with for loops

Comment: This is really really odd. I'm afraid I don't have an answer at the moment, but I'll try to think about it.

Comment: I think you are right. The problem is when data is divided. Tks a lot

Comment: Hum?? so when you call it with a `parfor`, you send the same amount of data to each worker and it does the exact same job and still you get different values?

Comment: @AnderBiguri exactly this. I thought the problem was solved, but it is not. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! I think I found it, but cant test it.

you have in your code:

```
redeT.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
```

If each of the workers chooses the data randomly, then its expected for them to have different results, aren't they?

Try the next:

```
per = cell(12,1);
parfor ii = 1 : 12
   rng(1); % set the seed for random number generation, so every time the number generated will be the same
   per{ii} = neuralTr(tSet,Y,CrossVal,Ycv);
end
per
```

Not sure if `neuralTr` does set the seed inside, but give it a go.

Comment: Excellent answer! I'm using it in mycode. Vielen danke my friend!